I get 'session.subscribe wasn't found' error in driver.script.add_console_message_handler
I try to use new feature selenium handlers to monitor console messages and JavaScript exceptions.
selenium.__version__='4.23.0' (driver.py:105)
My Remote WebDriver connection:
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
    chrome_options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")  
    chrome_options.enable_bidi = True
    chrome_options.browser_version = browser_version #variable from env


    selenoid_options = {}
    selenoid_options['enableVNC'] = True
    selenoid_options['se:cdp'] = True
    selenoid_options['se:cdpVersion'] = 125.0
    browser_version = str(os.environ["BROWSER_VERSION"])

    chrome_options.set_capability('selenoid:options', selenoid_options)
    # Добавляем нужные capabilities для CDP

    try:
        instance = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=url,
            options=chrome_options
            )
    except Exception:
        raise ACException(f"Could not create WebDriver Remote instance by {url}. Test cannot start")

    if hasattr(instance, 'start_devtools'):
        logging.info("Метод 'start_devtools' существует.")
    else:
        logging.error("Метод 'start_devtools' не существует.")
        return
    test_devtools, test_websocket = instance.start_devtools()

    # Подписка на события консоли
    def log_events(event):
        logging.warning(f"{event=}")
        if 'message' in event['params']:
            logging.warning(f"log_events {event['params']['message']=}")
    test_websocket.execute(test_devtools.runtime.enable())
    test_websocket.on(test_devtools.runtime.ConsoleAPICalled, log_events)

    # Подписка на события сети
    def network_event(event):
        logging.warning(f"Network event {event=}")

    test_websocket.on(test_devtools.network.RequestWillBeSent, network_event)
    test_websocket.on(test_devtools.network.ResponseReceived, network_event)

    test_websocket.execute(test_devtools.network.enable())

    log_items = []
    instance.script.add_console_message_handler(log_items.append)

On the line test_websocket.on(test_devtools.runtime.ConsoleAPICalled, log_events) I get the error:
2024-08-02 14:56:22 [ERROR] error from callback <function WebSocketConnection._start_ws.<locals>.on_message at 0x7fe1fb55e8e0>: 'ConsoleAPICalled' object is not subscriptable (_logging.py:77)

on the line:
instance.script.add_console_message_handler
I get `selenium.webdriver.remote.websocket connection.WebSocket Connection Exception:
# {'code': -32601, 'message': "'session.subscribe' wasn't found"}`

network requests work ok.
How to use ConsoleAPICalled and add_console_message_handler correctly for remote Webdriver?
I've tried:
bidi = instance.bidi_connection()
bidi.script.add_console_message_handler(log_items.append)

of cause, I got E AttributeError: '_AsyncGeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'script'

is this remote? Grid?

@browsermator yes)

I don't think remote hasBidi... (HasBidi interface) you might check that.  Try/catch a cast to HasBidi... I think there's a special way to treat that... but it's Java only?:   https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/#tracing-client-requests

@browsermator I get network events, and I see bidi in env opportunities
